# Fundamental theorem of line integrals

Tags: calculus

> Show that
>   $$\int_{-1,2}^{1,3}y^2\, dx+2xy\, dy$$
>   is independent of the path and evaluate the integral by a) using the fundamental theorem of line integrals and b) integrating along the line segment from $(-1,2)$ to $(1,3)$:
>   $$\left [  y^2\right ]_y=2y, \left [  2xy\right ]_x=2y$$
>   hence function independent of the path;now
>   $$F(1,3)=\left.xy^2  \right |_{1,3}=9$$
>   $$F(-1,2)=\left.xy^2  \right |_{-1,2}=-4$$
>   $$F(1,3)-F(-1,2)=9+4=13$$
>   now this may or may not be correct, but to answer part b) of the above question, I need a parametrised equation of the line - what would this be?

Comment: You can take a line with line equation: y=1/2*x+5/2 as parametric equation of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about
$(1-t)(-1,2)+(t)(1,3)$ for t between 0 and 1?

In general when parametrizing a straight, you take $t\in[0,1]$ and take the line
$(1-t)(x_0,y_0)+t(x_f,y_f)$

Answer (score 0):

Give distinct points $P,Q$, you can always parametrize the line segment connecting them by;

$$l: P(1-t)+ tQ \ ; t \in[0,1]$$